# How to get xap file in Xamarin portable project?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I just created a Blank Xamarin Portable Project in VS2015 Enterprise.

But I can't get xap file for Window Phone 8.1.

My project name is ABP so I have only ABP.dll, ABP.pdb, ABP.WinPhone.build.appxrecipe, ABP.WinPhone.exe etc.

I want my client to run using xap file on his win phone.

Is there a way for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Portable Project** is simply a **Class Library** that gives you a `DLL`. Its not an application. For that purpose you must create WinPhone application or Xamarin.Forms application(it will create a WinPhone application for you). Once you create WinPhone app, right click to project and select **Store->Create App Package** then follow the commands.

Comment: Thanks
So how can I use appxupload file created in AppPackage folder?
How can I run app in my phone?